# Character at index issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring

I have the following

```
NSString *timeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", time];
NSLog(@"Timestring is %@", timeString);
NSLog(@"the character at 1 is %d", [timeString characterAtIndex:1]);
```

and get the following in the print outs

> Timestring is 59
>       the character at 1 is 57

If I print out characterAtIndex:0 it prints out

```
Timestring is 59
the character at 0 is 53
```

I think it is printing out the char representation of the number.

How could I do this so that I can extract both numbers from e.g. 60 and use the 6 and the 0 to set an image.

e.g. @"%d.png"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

format specifier %d make nslog to treat corresponding value as integer, so in your case char value is treated as integer and integer value printed. To output actual character use %c specifier:

```
NSLog(@"the character at 1 is %c", [timeString characterAtIndex:1]);
```

Comment: Those are the hardest to spot by yourself ;)